# Is the function $f(x) = \frac{x-2}{x(x-2)}$ continuous?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

> Is the function
>   $$f(x)=\frac{x-2}{x(x-2)}$$
>   continuous?

I'm in high school and calculus is something that is not yet very comfortable to me. I read that we call this function continuous in its domain.

What does it exactly mean, because...

The points $0, 2$ are clearly not in its domain, so the definition of continuous function seems a bit weird $\lim_{x \to a^+}f(x) = \lim_{x \to a^-}f(x) = f(a) $ but for points $0,2,$ $\;f(a)$ is not valid as they are not in the domain, so how are we checking the continuity there. Also by this definition,  any function of form $\frac{anything}{0}$ is continuous then...

Also it seems a bit counter intuitive as at $0,\;$ $\lim_{x \to 0^+}f(x) =\infty, \lim_{x \to 0^-}f(x) = -\infty $ and yet we are calling it continouos.

Also what exactly is the difference between a "function being continouos" and a "function being continouos in its domain".

Comment: You can talk about continuity for its domain

Comment: @J.W.Tanner But in that case any function of $\frac{anything}{0}$ is continuous...

Comment: a function involving division by $0$ is not defined

Comment: The word is spelled continuous

Comment: @J.W.Tanner sorry, I meat limit of a function at some point....

Comment: as [José Carlos Santos](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/446262/jos%c3%a9-carlos-santos) answered below, just worry about continuity where the function is defined

Comment: Different authors use different definitions of "continuous."  If you are studying from a book, please look to see where it states its definitions. It will help if you reproduce them here verbatim.

Comment: all elementary functions are continuous in their respective domains

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct. The function is continuous, but the idea of continuity **only applies at points in the domain**. The points $0$ and $2$ are not in the domain.

You are also right to be "worried" about those points.

The function can be extended to a function $\hat{f}$ including $2$ in its domain (you must decide how to define $\hat{f}(2)$ in that case; the only value that results in a function that is still continuous is to define $\hat{f}(2)=\tfrac12$).

You can also extend this to an even larger extension $f^*$ which includes $0$ in its domain, but it will not be continuous no matter how you define $f^*(0)$ for the reasons you point out.

Part of what you should take away from this is that the domain needs to be explicit before you can say whether a function is continuous. A function can be discontinuous, but restricting its domain can result in a continuous function. And a function can be continuous, but it can have continuous or discontinuous extensions. The extensions/restrictions really are different functions.

Comment: So, I suppose I cannot just define the domain as R,It will always remain a subset of R\{0,2},untill and unless I specifically define the values of the function at X= 0 and X= 2

Comment: @DivMit : That's right. And if you do, then it will never be continuous as I mentioned because of the problem at $0$

Comment: Thank You so much.

Comment: Also can you please tell what exactly is the difference between a "function being continouos" and a "function being continouos in its domain". Or is it the same thing ?

Comment: @DivMit : They mean the same thing. A function is "continuous" if it is continuous at every point of its domain. A function might be continuous at some points, but not continuous at other points. But if it is continuous at every point (meaning every point of its domain), then it is simply said to be "continuous".

Comment: @DivMit : Also note the spelling is “continuous”, not “continouos”. It is “continu-“ + “-ous”.

Comment: Okay , Thanks ... I didn't know I was spelling it wrong the whole time :P

Answer (score 5):

It is natural to state that the domain $D$ of your function is the set of those real numbers $x$ at which that expression makes sense. So, in this case, $D=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0,2\}$. And, for each $a\in D$, we have $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$ indeed. Therefore $f$ *is* continuous. What happens outside $D$ does not matter.

Answer (score 2):

The so-called "calculus definition" of continuity is that a function $f$ is continuous at a point $a$ iff 
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a). $$
This equation says three non-trivial things (that is, any of them could fail):

1. The two-sided limit of $f$ exists at $a$.
2. The function is defined at $a.$
3. The limit of the function at $a$ is equal to the function's actual value at $a.$

For your function, all three things work for any $x$ not equal to $0$ or $2$ - that is, all numbers in its domain. That wouldn't be true for all functions. For example, the function
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0,\;&x<0 \\ 1,\:&x\ge 0\end{cases} $$
has a domain everywhere, but is discontinuous at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The domain of the function excludes $x=0$ and $x=2$. At other values, the function equals $$\dfrac1x,$$ which is indeed continuous (being the ratio of two continuous function, with a non-zero denominator).

Answer (score 1):

The function you have posted is an example of a *rational function*; i.e., a polynomial expression divided by a polynomial expression .

It is well known that rational functions are continuous wherever they are defined. That is what is meant by "continuous in its domain."

Moreover, rational functions are defined everywhere except at those $x$-values that would cause you to divide by $0$; in your case, over $\mathbb{R} - \lbrace 0 \rbrace - \lbrace 2 \rbrace $ = $(-\infty, 0) \cup (0, 2) \cup (2, \infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x)= \frac{x- 2}{x^2- 2x}= \frac{x- 2}{x(x- 2)}$ is not continuous at x= 2.  In fact, it is not even *defined* at x= 2.

We can say that $\frac{x- 2}{x(x- 2)}= \frac{1}{x}$ for all x **except** 2.  It is NOT equal to 1/2 at x= 2 because $\frac{0}{2(0)}$ is not defined- we cannot just "cancel" the "0"s.

If you were to graph $y= \frac{x- 2}{x(x- 2)}$ its graph would be exactly like $y= 1/x$ **except** there would be a "hole" in the graph at (2, 1/2).

(I was focusing on the "interesting case", x= 2.  Of course, this is also not continuous at x= 0.)

Comment: The points $x = 0$ and $x = 2$ are not in the domain of the function.  The function is continuous on its domain.